# HTC 626 bricked when trying to root the phone. What to do now?

Tags: unbricking

I have bricked my HTC 626. I was trying to root my phone.

I installed a recovery. As you can understand that I flashed recovery after unlocking bootloader. But I have s-on on phone. I then got some file on Google searching it for ways of recovery, super su, and `boot.img`.

I tried to open the phone in recovery mode but recovery wasn't working.
Then I thought flashing `boot.img` will work so I flashed it.
On the tutorial I found on the net there was a command for erasing the cache. Now it is not booting up. I tried to switch s-off. Didn't work.

Recovery did not work. I can only go through fastboot mode. ADB commands are working. I found some details that `ruu.exe` could help. But it is more complicated that I couldn't find proper `ruu`.

I did download HTCdev source file.

Here is `getvar` all details version: 0.5

```
version-bootloader: 3.19.0.0000
version-baseband: 1.0.U20402.1@50313
version-cpld: None
version-microp: None
version-main: 1.10.709.2
version-misc: PVT SHIP S-ON
imei2: Not Support
meid: 00000000000000
product: a32_ul
platform: hTCBmsm8916
modelid: 0PKX21000
cidnum: HTC__621
battery-status: good
battery-voltage: 0mV
partition-layout: Generic
security: on
build-mode: SHIP
boot-mode: FASTBOOT
hbootpreupdate: 11
gencheckpt: 0
mfg-name: 1001
```

What should I do to unbrick the phone?

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to bootloader (fastboot), do the following:

1. Unlock the bootloader
   General command:`fastboot oem unlock` (Not sure for your phone)
2. Flash a custom recovery: [CWM](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wt0r1q8xqse9zna/HTC-Desire-626GPLUS-dual-sim_150319__recovery_150509-171609.img?dl=0)
   Use the command: `fastboot flash recovery *recovery_name*.img`
3. [Download](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1oev7ymmhbnvfxc/AACzDFBZGANSY6bGmXInVs_va?dl=0) and Flash this [stock ROM](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1oev7ymmhbnvfxc/AACzDFBZGANSY6bGmXInVs_va?dl=0) from CWM: [CWM Backup](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1oev7ymmhbnvfxc/AACzDFBZGANSY6bGmXInVs_va?dl=0)

(Source: https://www.facebook.com/htc626gplusdev)

Comment: Here is the link for stock ROM: [https://yadi.sk/d/jX5b1Qw1hxh4t](https://yadi.sk/d/jX5b1Qw1hxh4t) Rename the downloaded file to 0PKXIMG.zip and place it in SD Card and flash it from fastboot mode using hboot option Source: [[q] need stock rom htc desire 626](http://forum.xda-developers.com/desire-626/help/q-stock-rom-htc-desire-626-t3159187/page2)

Comment: Can you give me ruu.exe file

Comment: I think you can flash that from [SP Flash tool](http://www.mediafire.com/download/5f5h3owa7s7y6g2/SP-Flash-Tool-v5.1352.01.zip)
Here's the scatter file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/drc102llimhn41f/MT6592_Android_scatter.txt?dl=0